# Запись путей из одной вершины графа в другую

Tags: delphi, pascal, delphi-7, рекурсия, графы

Есть ориентированный граф, нужно найти все возможные пути из одной его вершины в другую. Я нашел в интернете пример поиска по графам в глубину, но в нем ищется не сам путь, а количество возможный путей и из-за рекурсии я пока не могу понять, каким образом можно записывать маршрут. Поэтому у меня вопрос, как это можно делать? 
В коде ниже `a` *- матрица смежности(bool)*, `visited`*- массив посещенных(bool)*, `n`*- размер матрицы*, `v`*- начальная точка*, `x`*- конечная*, `cnt`*- количество возможных путей*

```
procedure dfs(var a:TArray; var visited: Tmas; n, v, x: integer; var cnt: integer);
var i: integer;
begin
    if v = x then begin
        Inc(cnt);
        exit;
    end;

    visited[v] := true;

    for i := 1 to n do begin
        if a[v, i] and not visited[i] then begin
            Route[v][i] := v;
            dfs(a, visited, n, i, x, cnt);
        end;
    end;

    visited[v] := false;
end;
```

Comment: у вас условие `x = v` сигнализирует что вы добрались до конечной вершины, и вы увеличиваете `cnt` - число найденных путей. В этот момент в `visited` у вас помечены все вершины, которые участвуют в текущем пути. Поскольку это просто множество вершин, а вам оно нужно в упорядоченном виде, то можете `visited` сделать не булевым массивом, а целочисленным, и нумеровать вершины по мере прохождения. Тогда отсортировав массив по возрастанию, получите путь. Ну или стэк можете реализовать помимо этого массива.

Comment: @teran, если в нем хранить значения, то по идее проверки тогда не будут работать + зачем его сортировать?

Comment: вместо `false` у вас будет `0`, а вместо `true` (что вершина посещена) будет номер шага пути. естественно придется модифицировать `not visited[i]` в `visited[i] = 0`.

Comment: ну сортировать при выводе пути, если у ваc visited (bool)  выглядит как `[0,1,1,0,0,1]` значит в пути у вас встречаются вершины 2-3-5. Если вы начнете считать глубину рекурсии (шагов пути), то массив станет например `[0,2,1,0,0,3]`  И вот чтобы вывести путь в нормально порядке `3-2-5` (индексы - номера вершин, значения - шаг в пути) сортировка и потребуется. Ну можно и не прямо уж сортировать, это так, условно. вам нужно вывести индексы в порядке возрастания значений

Comment: @teran, а где ее выхватывать? Она же может в цикле несколько раз поменяться

Comment: глубину рекурсии то? добавьте в параметры функции `z: integer = 1`, и при рекурсивном вызове передавайте `z+1`, ну и `visited[i] = z;`

Comment: @teran, мне не глубина нужна, а список вершин, которые надо посетить, чтобы добраться до последней вершины.

Comment: список вершин у вас в `visited`, а с помощью глубины вы получите порядок, в котором эти вершины обходить надо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

не на чем проверять, нет под рукой ни IDE, ни тестовых данных. Но по итогам комментов, смотрите в следующем направлении:

`visited` - целочисленный массив по числу вершин графа. `0` - вершина не посещалась, иначе число - порядковый номер в пути `1..M`, где `M` дина пути. В параметры функции вводим глубину рекурсии `z`, это каждый новый шаг пути.

```
procedure dfs(var a:TArray; var visited: Tmas; n, v, x: integer; 
              var cnt: integer; 
              z : integer = 1);
var i: integer;

     procedure printPath();
     var k,m : integer;  
     begin

        for k := 1 to z do begin              // количество узлов в пути 
           for m := 1 to n do begin           // длина visited, число вершин
               if visited[m] = k then begin   // нашли номер шага пути 
                  write('->', m);           // номер вершины
                  break;
               end;
           end;
        end;
        writeln();
     end;

begin 
    if v = x then begin             // дошли в конечную точку Х
        Inc(cnt);                   // увеличили число путей
        printPath();                // напечатали путь
        exit;                       // вернулись к предыдущему шагу пути
    end;

    visited[v] := z;                // сейчас мы посещаем вершину v

    for i := 1 to n do begin                     // просматриваем другие точки
        if a[v, i] and                           // если i-я и текущая связаны
           (visited[i] = 0) then begin           // и i-я еще не посещалась  
            dfs(a, visited, n, i, x, cnt, z+1);  // то идем в i-ю
        end;
    end;

    visited[v] := 0;     // возвращаемся к предыдущему шагу пути
                         // выходим из рекурсии, 
                         // освобождая вершину v        
end;
```

данный алгоритм работает таким образом, что каждый  новый вызов рекурсии дает переход к следующей точке вглубь. При попадании в новый виток рекурсии, раньше мы просто запоминали, что данная вершина посещена. Теперь же мы записываем туда число, информирующее, что посещена она шаге `z`.
И вот когда мы пришли в искомую точку, то наш путь завершен и в массиве `visited` у записано, в каком порядке надо проходить вершины, чтобы добраться сюда. индексы массива эта вершины, а значения это номер шага.

Теперь остается вывести путь. Мы знаем, что его длина равно текущему `z` (т.е. сколько переходов вглубь мы сделали). Так что циклом от 1 до z находим соответствующее значение в массиве. и выводим вершину (индекс).

*зы: алгоритм сам по себе прост как валенок. Если у вас затруднения рекурсией, то нарисуйте на бумаге простенький граф, нарисуйте массивы данных, и с карандашом решите этот алгоритм на листе. это быстро все расставит на свои места.*